# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have following code

```
<div id="vue-instance">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
  },
  ready:function(){
    this.loadCountries();
  },
  methods:{
        loadCountries(){
            this.$http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all',function(data){
                console.log(data);
          })
      }
  }
});
```

When I run the above code it gives me following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

I have a fiddle

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/183/)

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you have vue-resource installed and configured?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247812/this-http-vuejs-not-set

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal how to install that on jsFiddle ?

Comment: Vue Resource is deprecated. Use Axios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$http.get` is from [Vue Resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource). Make sure you are pulling that in properly by adding `vue-resource` to your `package.json`, install it via `npm install` and in code:

```
var Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));
```

To use this in fiddle, you have to add `vue-resource` [cdn link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.2.0/vue-resource.js) in external resources and use following in code:

```
Vue.use(VueResource)
```

See working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/187/

Comment: how to do that in the fiddle ? All I want to do is an Ajax Call is there any other way  ?

Comment: I still can't see anything in the console although I see that the error is gone , and I test manually the url works fine

Comment: @Vikram There were few more errors in your code, see working solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/187/). Let me know in case of any query.

Comment: it would be good if you can update that link in the Answer as well . So that its useful for other people

Comment: @Saurabh Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529345/how-can-i-solve-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-in

Answer (score 4):

In order to use **$http** you must install the **vue-resource** middleware first. You can use the following command to install it.

```
npm install vue-resource --save
```

After its installed go to your **main.js** file and import the **vue resource** as follows

```
import vueResource from 'vue-resource'
```

Now its imported so we just have to call the **use** method of **Vue** to work with this middleware. You can call the **use** method as follows.

```
Vue.use(vueResource)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have no plugin for vue-resource your this.$http is undefined. 
To add Vue-resource on js-fiddle add https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/vue@2.0.0-rc.4,vue.resource@1.0.0 to the external scripts section.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue of the following mode:

```
npm install bootstrap-vue --save
npm install vue-resource --save
```

in main.js

```
import Vue from './bootstrap'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

create bootstrap.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)

export { Vue }
```

In App.vue

```
this.$http.get('/api/module/all').then(...
```

Answer (score 0):

I used another way as of Oct 2019. I first installed using NPM like this

```
npm install axios --save
```

I used this below later and doing this below got rid of the error.

```
import  axios  from 'axios';
```