# VueJS http get request

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js

Trying to send an http get request using Vue js. Can't see any problems with the logic, not too experienced using vuejs though.

Keep getting these two errors:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'get' of undefined"

and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

```
var owm = new Vue({
  el: '#owm',
  data: {
    debug: true,
    weather: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadWeather: function() {
      this.$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=stockholm&type=like&appid=766b78c39446a8fa6313c3b7b2063ade', function(data, status, request){
        if(status == 200)
        {
          this.weather = data;
          console.log(this.weather);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.loadWeather();
  }
});
```

Updated the code using vue resource, the errors are gone but it won't console log any data, what could be wrong?

```
Vue.use(VueResource);
var owm = new Vue({
  el: '#owm',
  data: {
    weather: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadWeather: function() {
      this.$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=stockholm&type=like&appid=[API KEY]', function(data, status, request){
        if(status == 200)
        {
          this.weather = data;
          console.log(this.weather);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.loadWeather();
  }
});
```

EDIT:
This code works, don't really understand the .then function though and why the request won't work with the callback function but the .then function does.

```
this.$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=stockholm&type=like&appid=[API KEY]').then((data) => {
  this.weather = data;
  console.log(this.weather);
```

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387414/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-in-vuejs

Comment: But do not use `vue-resorce` package. It is deprecated now. Read this about alternatives: https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4

Comment: installed vue resource and running : var Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(require('vue-resource')); in the code, now i get the error saying "require is not defined"

Answer (score 8):

I tried a sample on my machine .you are using $http in wrong way. refer the docs.Since $http resolves a promise its callback can be handled inside a then function. This worked for me:

```
 loadWeather: function() {
    var self=this;
  this.$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=stockholm&type=like&appid=766b78c39446a8fa6313c3b7b2063ade').then(function(response){
    if(response.status == "200"){
        console.log(response);
    self.weather = response.data.list[0].weather // use self instead of this
    }


  })
```

Comment: Still not getting any data

Comment: Are you able to make the request successfully?? or do you get any error while sending the request ? can you send the screenshot of response from network panel in debug tool.

Comment: Getting no errors with the request, but no data returned either

Comment: Ran your code, still not returning any data. This code works for me though   this.$http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + this.userInput + this.apiKey).then((data) => {}, but not familiar with what the .then function does.