# Vue.js in laravel does not return GET request with Ajax

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-resource

I'm trying to create a laravel app with a Vue.js to call a controller response, I've tried it with ajax alone and it works, but with Vue the GET method seems not working, there are also no error code for me to debug.

here is my Vue.js

```
<template>
<div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item"  v-for="unregboard in unregboards" :key="unregboard.boardId"> 
            {{ unregboard.boardName }}  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data(){
        return{
            unregboards:[]
        }
    } , created: function(){
        this.fetchUnreg()
    }, methods:{
        fetchUnreg: function () {
            console.log("test"); //this works
            this.$http.get('/registerlist', function(resp){
                this.unregboards = resp.unRegBoards;
                console.log(resp.unRegBoards);
                console.log('test'); // This doesn't
            }).bind(this);
        }
    } 

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**UPDATE**

I have fixed something and the code, I had my hopes up, because unlike before I was able to log my json response, check my code below:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"  v-for="unregboard in unregboards" :key="unregboard.boardId"> 
                {{ unregboard["boardName"] }}  
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data(){
        return{
            unregboards:[]
        }
    } , created: function(){
        this.fetchUnreg()
    }, methods:{
        fetchUnreg: function () {
            console.log("test");
            $.get('/registerlist', function(resp){
                this.unregboards = resp.unRegBoards;
                console.log(resp.unRegBoards);
            });
        }
    } 

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

The problem is on the template, I does not return anything on the "unregboards" Vue.js's For loop

**Additional Info**
this is the json file that's being returned:

```
{
   "regBoards":[
      {
         "boardName":"Client 1",
         "boardId":"594a0ec09ad35eba4434142r",
         "organization":"Dream Inc."
      },
      {
         "boardName":"Welcome Board",
         "boardId":"58d311eeace6df3821107648",
         "organization":null
      }
   ],
   "unRegBoards":[
      {
         "boardName":"Client 2",
         "boardId":"5935fc808823fdbe2875d63g",
         "organization":"Dream Inc."
      },
      {
         "boardName":"Client 3",
         "boardId":"59190bf0b27a6f308820rh5u",
         "organization":"Dream Inc."
      },
      {
         "boardName":"Client 4",
         "boardId":"58a5006e9985e088628f634g",
         "organization":"Dream Inc."
      },

   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack/browserify ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387414/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-in-vuejs

Comment: It's not the same, I've already installed vue-resources, As I said it returns no error, as you can see in the code that I've attached I've tried two console.log, the other one works the other doesn't.

Comment: try like this this.$http.get('/registerlist').then(
function (response) {

}, function (error) {
});

Comment: I've already tried that still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [vue-resource documentation](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#options), there is no second *callback* argument passed to the `.get()` method, only *`options`*.

Assuming the response body is JSON, you also should be parsing the response using the `.json()` method. Right now, you're assigning `undefined` to your `data` property.

```
fetchUnreg: function () {
  this.$http.get('/registerlist').then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => {
    this.unregboards = data
    console.log(this.unRegBoards)
    console.log('test')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
this.$http.get('/registerlist').then(
    response => {
        this.unregboards = response.data
    }
);
```

Comment: what happen when you log response.body ?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: Instead of using function syntax, use arrow functions and try i have updated code