# Laravel's Gate Authorization inside a vue component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

Using the Laravel's Gate / Authorization. I can use it in my blade template by simply doing..

```
@can('edit-post')
    <button></button>
@endcan
```

However, what if the button is inside a vue component, how can I apply the @can to authorize the user?

Comment: use ajax to get user's permission from laravel to vue.

Comment: can you provide an example sir?

Comment: please [check this and try](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42387414/2815635)

Comment: why can't use vue inline template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your permission from laravel to global javascript variable or you can load it using ajax call

```
window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
                'userId' => Auth::user()->id,
                'permissions' => Auth::user()->permissions()->pluck('name')->toArray()
            ]); ?>
```

Then create a vue directive

```
Vue.directive('can', function (el, binding) {
  return Laravel.permissions.indexOf(binding) !== -1;
})
```

Now apply it to your button

```
<button v-can="editStuff">You can edit this thing</button>
```

You can look it here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/roles-and-permissions-in-vue

Answer (score 0):

Use vue inline-template. That can hold blade features..